# take data from ip adress and display on my android application

Tags: android

I have created an application in android which displays the continuous unit production going on the plant.

the data  displayed in the application is taken from an I.P.Address.can anyone tell me how do I display the data from I.P.Address into my app

Comment: What do you mean, the data from an IP address? The address is just a number. Do you mean that you make a HTTP request to that IP and you want the content?

Comment: yes..the pc of that ipadress contains data i want to diplay in my app

Comment: i am almost a newbie for the android so if u could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you host a website or webserver at the IP address, you can read how you can download the content of the webpage [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). If you want to display the webpage, you can use a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

If you are not using a HTTP protocol, but just FTP, you can read what to do [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html).

**edit**

FTP example:

```
   URL url = new URL("ftp://1.2.3.4/test.csv");
   URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
   InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
   String result = "";

   try {
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
     String line;
     while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
       result += line;
      }
     yourTextView.setText(result);
    finally {
     in.close();
   }
 }
```

Comment: i want to use http protocol.how do i do it?

Comment: You could run an [apache server](http://httpd.apache.org/) on the machine of which you have the IP address.

Comment: u r not exactly understanding what i m wanting to ask..i have a text field in which i want to display the  production rate  whose value is changing in seconds .this production rate value is available on a site as well on the pc..how do i do it?

Comment: How is it available at a site? You have to use a *service* on a machine in order to access its data from the outside world.

Comment: on the machine i have a folder with a notepad file which contains data seperatd by ;..these seperated data are to be displayed in the different textfield.

Comment: You can't just acccess files on a machine of which you know the IP address. In order to expose the file, you need to run a service like [FTP](http://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server).

Comment: dats what i m asking u how to do it...am still learning android..so please can u tell me how will i do it?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Android. This is something you have to do on the *host* system. On the Android device you just have to use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html).

Comment: and how do i display the data recievied in the textfield?

Comment: See my edit. If you have further questions, I would advice you to start a new topic for that.